# How do I put a border around merged cells in Excel using .Net?

Tags: .net, excel-interop

How do I apply a border around merged cells? (I don't mind if it is in VB, c#...)
My code only apply a border around the first cell.

My code:

```
Range range = sheet.Cells[r,c]; // Select first cell in a group.
range.Borders = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

Thank you!

Comment: sheet.get_Range("A1") also don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Range chartrange = worksheet.Range["a5", "d8"];
            chartrange.Merge();

            chartrange = worksheet.Range["a5", "d8"];
            chartrange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble;
            chartrange.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

This works as well. so, you can choose merged cells range again and apply border on it.

Comment: Thank you! It works well as you said. Looks like I have no other option but to detect the cells that is in the merge, select them all, and then put a border around it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
  Range chartrange = worksheet.Range["a5", "c8"];
  chartrange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDot;
  chartrange.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
  chartrange.Merge();
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, but I am updating a sheet with cells that is already merged.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Border around multiple cells in Interop.Excel:

```
Excel.Range formatRange;
formatRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("b2", "e9");
formatRange.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous,
Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic,
Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic);
```